# Conditional Django migration based on a field only present in new version

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations, backwards-compatibility

My app that currently depends on Postgres and Django's Postgres-only `JSONField`. The field works well and I've no interest in another project, but I have prospective-users who want to use my app, but can't while it relies on Postgres.

Django 3.1 has a cross-platform version of this field —which will work for my needs— but I don't want to force everybody up to Django 3.1; I would like to offer people a choice between Postgres or Django 3.1+. On paper, this is simple enough with a conditional import...

```
try:
    from django.db.models import JSONField
except ImportError:
    from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
```

And if I installed Django 3.1 and generated a migration, it could take me from `django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField` to `django.db.models.JSONField`. But...

- New users will still execute the initial migration. **I will still have a dependency on Postgres.**
- Sub-Django 3.1 users won't be able to execute the new migration. **I now have a dependency on Django 3.1.**

This is worse than when I started. How do I do this sort of field migration in a way that will work for everybody?

Comment: Presumably you're supplying the migrations with your app. Can't you use similar conditional code within the migration file to decide which field to add?

Comment: I am, and initially (as I've said to Tom's answer below) that would work, but what happens to people who migrated originally with the contrib.postgres version, who upgrade Django and how have runtime code using the new version? I'm not sure there is any stateful changes that need to be made with *this* field, but I feel like there aught to be a way to work out what's happened before.

Comment: The new `JSONField` has the same representation in PostgreSQL as the old one, so it will be fine for your current users to use the new model field with their existing databases. I didn't quite understand the end of your comment, you're wondering if there's a more general solution?

Comment: Basically, the solution is the combination Tom Carrick and Arrakal Abu: edit past migrations and current model definitions to generate a consistent import reference across migration history for one version of the software. An autogenerated migration will use a full import path and detect that import path of the field changed. However, if the import path is consistent, no changes are detected. So even if it is upgraded, the old migrations and new definition will all reference the new path as if nothing changed.

Answer (score 10):

Migrations are just code. Just because they're auto-generated doesn't mean you shouldn't change them. You're encouraged to, at least to check they're generated correctly, but also there's no harm in writing them yourself.

This works for me:

Model:

```py
from django.db import models

try:
    from django.db.models import JSONField
except ImportError:
    from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    stuff = JSONField()
```

Migration:

```py
from django.db import migrations, models

try:
    from django.db.models import JSONField
except ImportError:
    from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [('testapp', '0001_initial')]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MyModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('stuff', JSONField()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Keep in mind that if you need to change this field in the future, you will need to go through this process again.

Comment: This is for a reusable app, used by people [currently] on Django 2.x and 3.x. A single named migration will work at the time they run it, but if they upgrade Django later on, they'll still be on the migration that ran at the time, if you see what I mean. Their database will be using the old state, the code will be expecting the new state. How do I migrate their state onto the "native" version?

Comment: It looks like it "just works" for me. I've tested the following cases: Install on 2.2, stay there. Install on 3.1, stay there. Install on 2.2 (running the migration), then upgrading Django to 3.1b1 and running migrate again. Running `makemigrations` correctly shows "No changes detected", so it seems like when JSONField was added, a variation on this was taken into account, so Django sees them as the same field, without changes.

Comment: Thinking on it a few seconds more, I'm not sure there's anything fancy going on here. Django just sees there's no change between the model and the migration, as both change depending on the import. As they have the same API, there shouldn't be any problem, even when the version in the postgres contrib package is removed. So it seems pretty future-proof. When the field is removed from there, you can simply remove the other import when you're ready to drop support for 2.2, and it'll continue to work.

Comment: I suggest to edit the last sentence: "If you need to *create a new migration of your app* in the future, you will need to *modify the import of JSONField the same way in any new migration". It must be edited this way in all old migrations and it should continue until you terminate support of Django < 3.1. (probably not before the mainstream deadline of all previous version in April 2022) This can be probably good for you, but I will write a solution better for projects where the models are in active development.

Answer (score 5):

I have got this from [Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/779e615e362108862f1681f965ee9e4f1d0ae6d2/django/contrib/postgres/fields/jsonb.py#L13)

> ```
> from django.db.models import JSONField as BuiltinJSONField
>
> class JSONField(BuiltinJSONField):
>     system_check_deprecated_details = {
>         'msg': (
>             'django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField is deprecated. Support '
>             'for it (except in historical migrations) will be removed in '
>             'Django 4.0.'
>         ),
>         'hint': 'Use django.db.models.JSONField instead.',
>         'id': 'fields.W904',
>     }
> ```

This indicates that, `django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField` is going to be deprecated. Also, Django uses the `django.db.models.JSONField` as postgres special JSONField.

Apart from that, I have generated the SQL command using [**`sqlmigrate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate) command and it was like,

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model MyModel
--
CREATE TABLE "myapp_mymodel" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "stuff" jsonb NOT NULL);
COMMIT;
```

**Surprisingly, I have got same SQL command using `Django==3.0` and `Django==3.1` and in the database, the field is a `jsonb` type**

These pieces of information conclude that you don't have to worry about this new JSONField upgrade.

#### What changes need to be done?

You don't need to generate a **new migration file**, but **edit** existing migration files which have `django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField` reference with the `try...except` block.

That's it!!!

Answer (score 4):

**All new migrations will be correct automatically** if this solution with a [deconstruct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#custom-field-deconstruct-method) method will be used.

You can create a compatible custom JSONField that encapsulates both variants.

Create a small file `fields.py` in your application:

```py
try:
    from django.db.models import JSONField as OrigJSONField
except ImportError:
    from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField as OrigJSONField


class JSONField(OrigJSONField):
    def deconstruct(self):
        # the original path was 'django.db.models.JSONField' or 'django.contrib.postgres.fields....'
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        # Substitute 'my_app' by your application name everywhere.
        path = 'my_app.fields.JSONField'
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

Change a line in your `models.py`:

```py
from my_app.fields import JSONField
```

Edit all existing migrations that use a JSONField:

```py
import my_app.fields
    ...
        ('stuff', my_app.fields.JSONField()),
```

(or equivalently)

```py
from my_app.fields import JSONField
    ...
        ('stuff', JSONField()).
```

No migration is created after that because no difference is found by makemigrations.

All future `makemigrations` after a changed model will be created automatically with `my_app.fields.JSONField()`. Compatibility is a benefit of this solution.

---

**Reflection** about [Django Release Notes 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#jsonfield-for-all-supported-database-backends) and future:

They describe a plain upgrade that requires to create a new migration that only upgrades the import path, but it generates no SQL e.g. by `sqlmigrate`. It is easier than to edit old migrations.

Maybe you you also upgrade in two years to Django >= 3.1 only and you will have two alternatives:

A) Only the import in `models.py` will be edited and you create a new nearly empty formal migration similarly to release notes. You will be not able to remove the import path `my_app.fields.JSONField` because it must be importable from old migrations similarly that Django can never remove the path `django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField`. The file `my_app/fields.py` could be simplified to one line `from django.db.models import JSONField as JSONField` after an unconditional upgrade of requirements.

B) Editing old migrations again to only the new JSONField is possible, but unreasonable.

(It is every user's responsibility that an edit in a migrations file doesn't require a changed database state and all migrations remain consistent each other. That is why not much about it can be found, except such clear cases.)

Comment: Awesome answer: I did create the custom JSONField before even reading your answer, but the overriding of the ``decontruct`` method is great! Now I don't need to worry about replacing the JSONField in new migrations. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I gave point to Tom Carrick for his answer but I think it should also include the usage of [`Meta.required_db_vendor = 'postgres'`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/) on Django < 3.1

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models

try:
    from django.db.models import JSONField
    postgres_only = False
except ImportError:
    from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
    postgres_only = True

class MyModel(models.Model):
    stuff = JSONField()

    class Meta:
        if postgres_only:
            required_db_vendor = 'postgres'
```

```py
# migrations/0001_initial.py
from django.db import migrations, models

try:
    from django.db.models import JSONField
    postgres_only = False
except ImportError:
    from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
    postgres_only = True


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [('testapp', '0001_initial')]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MyModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('stuff', JSONField()),
            ],
            options={'required_db_vendor': 'postgres'} if postgres_only else None,
        ),
    ]
```

This will ensure that users of your reusable app cannot use it on a different database than PostgreSQL on Django < 3.1 and seamlessly enable support on 3.1 without requiring a migration on PostgreSQL users using your library and updating to Django 3.1.

Comment: I think that a migration on Postgres JSONField will fail correctly anyway on another backend and I hope that the error message would be crear. I think that the option `required_db_vendor` is especially needful for custom migrations based on RunPython or RunSQL.